# Talking 2D/3D characters for personal assistant type application

Tags: c#, animation

I am working on a project [Virtual Personal Assistant Using Kinect](http://virtualpa.codeplex.com) i wanted to add a animated character which talks back to the user, but i have no idea how to do this i came across iclone5 but it can just prerecord something, i am already using system.speech for speech synthesis but i only want the character animation part,i know that this is close to game animation but i have no idea of the process.

can anyone provide any pointers about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what part exactly you need help with, so I'll guess...

If you are going the 3d route, you can use the free 3d modelling software [blender](http://www.blender.org/). I found this [lip sync tutorial](http://download.blender.org/documentation/oldsite/oldsite.blender3d.org/46_Blender%20tutorial%20Lip%20Syncing.html) and another [lip sync tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D%3a_Noob_to_Pro/Advanced_Tutorials/Advanced_Animation/Guided_tour/Mesh/Shape/Sync) you can use. There you can animate the visemes to the specific phonemes. I don't know enough of system.speech to know if you have access to the converted phonemes of the text. It could also be helpful to look at [espeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thank you, but these are easily accomplished by  [iclone5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qahyP3kGpEQ) i don't mind buying it, but i have to play it real-time when i ask it "What's the news?" then it should start reading a set of data which comes from google news api and it shouldn't look like its two images flipped one after the other, but there should be facial expressions, and different expressions for different phonemes or predefined words which should change facial features.

Answer (score 0):

Largely left to succumb to bitrot now, but [MS Agent](http://www.microsoft.com/products/msagent/main.aspx) might fit the bill...

Comment: Thanks, is there something a little more complex.